# $Promise error in Angular 1.3 while performing a PUT request $resource

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have tried to update a project currently working with Angular 1.2.* to 1.3.6 however I get an error when ever I try to make a PUT request to my REST server (running a MEAN stack) with $resource and $http.

The data object being sent has $promise and $resolve attached to the object in Angular 1.3 which failed on Mongo. In Angular 1.2. the $promise etc has been removed and works. I have no idea how or what to change to get this to work? Any thoughts.

```
{"_id":"53ca230aeddbcb2c187254eb" "$promise":{},"$resolved":true}
```

The following Mongo error is given

The dollar ($) prefixed field '$Promise' ... is not valid for storage

I understand why the error is throw I just want to know how to strip the $promise out as in Angular 1.2.

Here is my code block

```
   var projResource = $resource('/api/project/:projId', { projId: '@id' },
        { 'update': { method: 'PUT', params: { projId: '@id'}} });

   function saveProject(project, projId) {
        projResource.get({ projId: projId });
        return projResource.update({ projId: projId }, project);
    }
```

Comment: `Resourse.prototype` has a `.toJSON` method that deletes the `$promise` and `$resolved` properties.  The `toJSON` method [will be called by `JSON.stringify` automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior).  So if you are seeing these properties sent to your server, then I suspect that something else has changed in your project that has interfered with either `JSON.stringify` and/or `Resource.prototype.toJSON`.

Comment: @Carl G I am sure you are correct thanks for the feedback. I rebuild the project as I could not find the error. I will close the question as it was most likely bad code.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to identify the error describe above. I recreate the project for scratch as a new angular 1.3 project and move everything across and now it is working correctly.

It was likely poor code.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using angular-resource 1.2.x. After upgrading to 1.3.x it stopped adding those properties to my JSON response